# Unhandled rejections in Express applications

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

I have a lot of ES6 promise based code running inside my express app. If there is an error that is never caught I'm using the following code to deal with it:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p) {
  console.log("Unhandled Rejection:", reason.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

This works fine for debugging purposes.

In production however I would like to trigger the 500 error handler, to show the user the standard "Something went wrong" page. I have this catch all error handler that currently works for other exceptions:

```
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500);
  res.render('500');
});
```

Putting the unhandledRejection inside a middleware does not work as it's async and offen results in a `Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.`

How would I go about rendering the 500 page on an `unhandledRejection`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Putting the unhandledRejection inside a middleware...often results in a `Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.`

Make a slight change to your error handler:

```
// production error handler
const HTTP_SERVER_ERROR = 500;
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (res.headersSent) {
    return next(err);
  }

  return res.status(err.status || HTTP_SERVER_ERROR).render('500');
});
```

From the [ExpressJS Documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html):

> Express comes with an in-built error handler, which takes care of any errors that might be encountered in the app. This default error-handling middleware is added at the end of the middleware stack.
>
> If you pass an error to next() and you do not handle it in an error handler, it will be handled by the built-in error handler - the error will be written to the client with the stack trace. The stack trace is not included in the production environment.
>
> > Set the environment variable NODE_ENV to “production”, to run the app in production mode.
>
> If you call next() with an error after you have started writing the response, for instance if you encounter an error while streaming the response to the client, Express’ default error handler will close the connection and make the request be considered failed.
>
> So when you add a custom error handler you will want to delegate to the default error handling mechanisms in express, when the headers have already been sent to the client.

Comment: hi. please add more code. i do not know how to handle unhandledRejection  using this code `process.on('unhandledRejection', error => { /* what should i do here */ });` in a express app

Answer (score 24):

I'm using `next` argument as a `catch` callback(aka errback)
to forward any unhandled rejection to express error handler:

```
app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  somePromise
    .then(function (result) {
      res.send(result);
    })
    .catch(next); // <----- NOTICE!
}
```

or shorter form:

```
app.get('/foo', function (req, res, next) {
  somePromise
    .then(function (result) {
       res.send(result); 
    }, next); // <----- NOTICE!
}
```

and then we could emit meaningful error response
with `err` argument in express error handler.

for example,

```
app.use(function (err, req, res, /*unused*/ next) {
  // bookshelf.js model not found error
  if (err.name === 'CustomError' && err.message === 'EmptyResponse') {
    return res.status(404).send('Not Found');
  }
  // ... more error cases...
  return res.status(500).send('Unknown Error');
});
```

IMHO, global `unhandledRejection` event is not the ultimate answer.

for example, this is prone to memory leak:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p) {
    console.log("Unhandled Rejection:", reason.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Unknown Error');
    //or next(reason);
  });
});
```

but this is **TOO** heavy:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var l = process.once('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p) {
    console.log("Unhandled Rejection:", reason.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Unknown Error');
    //next(reason);
  });
  next();
  process.removeEventLister('unhandledRejection', l);
});
```

IMHO, expressjs needs better support for Promise.

Comment: so we should always use `next` to handle errors and there is no global error handler for promise rejection :(  this is so bad!

Comment: why you need to remove the `unhandledRejection` event listener if you can add the listener once?

Comment: According to the docs `Adds a one-time listener function for the event named eventName. The next time eventName is triggered, this listener is removed and then invoked.` - https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_event_removelistener

Comment: @iolo You mention `Too heavy`, can you please explain?

Comment: @loretoparisi That doc reference is wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 17):

[express-promise-router](https://github.com/express-promise-router/express-promise-router) was made to solve exactly this problem. It allows your routes to return promises, and will call `next(err)` if such a promise is rejected with an error.

Comment: I think nowadays this is really the way to go; it's a lot less to remember and will be much cleaner than trying to sprinkle error-catching logic throughout your code.

Answer (score 11):

By default, if your request is `async` function that throws an error, express doesn't pass errors to the middleware.
Instead `process.on('unhandledRejection', callback)` is called, and the request will block.

The library [express-async-errors](https://github.com/davidbanham/express-async-errors) was created to solve these errors.

You need to add `require('express-async-errors');` to your code and the library will make sure that all your functions come to the handlers.
Even if it's an unhandled rejection.

Comment: nice! with that lib this is dead simple. I would encourage to build your own error handler middleware and try catch all of your async call and call next(err) inside catchs but if you want to save time, this libs seems to work just fine!

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a clean way to handle it, Express 5 now handle async promises by design:

> Starting with Express 5, route handlers and middleware that return a
> Promise will call next(value) automatically when they reject or throw
> an error. For example

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: I've been waiting a long time for Express 5 to evolve from beta. Does anyone have an informed prediction about when this might happen?

Comment: @LonnieBest I have no idea but if it can reassure you, I have used the beta in production for a few months on a website with a few thousands daily visits

Comment: @SebastienHorin Well, thank you for that testimony. I'll go ahead and upgrade and see if it works good for me too.

Comment: So far, my app won't run in Express 5 due to a strange error: `413,"request entity too large",{limit:s,received:u,type:"entity.too`, I've set limits to 100MB and it still won't run it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are using Express and some promise-based code like so:

`readFile()
  .then(readAnotherFile)
  .then(doSomethingElse)
  .then(...)`

Add a `.catch(next)` to the end of your promise chain and Express's middleware will successfully handle both synchronous/asynchronous code using your production error handler.

Here's a great article that goes in-depth to what you are looking for: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/async-error-handling-expressjs-es7-promises-generators/