# How to handle unhandledRejection and uncaughtException in Expressjs to avoid ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In Expressjs I'm handling the [unhandledRejection](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-unhandledrejection) and [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#event-uncaughtexception) events defining two middleware, one for `unhandledRejectionHandler` and one for `unhandledExceptionHandler`, respectively:

```
const unhandledRejectionHandler = (req, res, next) => {
    process.setMaxListeners(process.getMaxListeners() + 1);
    process.once('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p) { // unhandledRejection
        self.logger.error("[unhandledRejection] error code:%d message:%s stack:%@:\n%@", reason.code, reason.message, reason.stack);
        if (res.headersSent) {
            next();
        } else {
            var errorMessage = APIHelper.createErrorMessage(500, '', '', reason.message);
            res.status(500);
            res.send(errorMessage);
            res.end();
        }
        process.setMaxListeners(Math.max(process.getMaxListeners() - 1, 0));
    });
    next();
};
```

and

```
const unhandledExceptionHandler = (req, res, next) => {
...
```

then registered as usual:

```
self.app.use(unhandledRejectionHandler);
self.app.use(unhandledExceptionHandler);
```

where I'm using [setMaxListeners](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#emittersetmaxlistenersn) to prevent the warning limit of 10 max listeners. The problem is that even checking the bool [headersSent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responseheaderssent) of [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpserverresponse) class, I may still get the error

```
ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled rejections in Express applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410101/unhandled-rejections-in-express-applications)

Comment: thanks, apparently I'm using the same approach, but it does not work as expected with the proposed solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that `res.headersSent` is `true`? It looks like it calls` res.send()` multiple times..